# jQuery getting id of hovered element in nested commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for something similar to `this.id` for the hovered element. When I plug `this.id` into the `return...` part the id returned is the id `container`. Any ideas how to jump that and go to the original hovered element's id?

```
$("#results p").hover(function() {
     $("#container").prepend(function() {
          return "<div id=\"tooltip\"><div id=\"tooltip-inside\">" + e.target.id + "</div></div>";
     });
}, function() {
     $("#tooltip, #tooltip-inside").remove();   
});
```

Comment: Where is `e` object defined? It should be defined as handler argument of `hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read id from `target` object in `hover` callback:

```
$("#results p").hover(function(e) {
     var id = e.target.id;
     $("#container").prepend(function() {
          return "<div id=\"tooltip\"><div id=\"tooltip-inside\">" + id  + "</div></div>";
     });
}, function() {
     $("#tooltip, #tooltip-inside").remove();   
});
```

Comment: It's always something simple. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#results p").hover(function() {
     var hovered = $(this);
     $("#container").prepend('<div id="tooltip"><div id="tooltip-inside">'+hovered.attr('id')+'</div></div>');
}, function() {
     $("#tooltip").remove();   
});
```

i also improved the code abit.

And if you already using jQuery why not use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#results p").hover(function() {
     // get a reference value using jQuery. "this" refers to the element being hovered over
     var myId = $(this).attr('id');
     $("#container").prepend(function() {
          return "<div id=\"tooltip\"><div id=\"tooltip-inside\">" + myId + "</div></div>";
     });
}, function() {
     $("#tooltip, #tooltip-inside").remove();   
});
```